# Reshape query results in pure PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have a SQL query result table like this :

```
Date,metric,value
1,x,2
2,x,3
2,y,5
3,y,8
3,z,9
```

And I would like to get the sum by day for each metric ( filling with 0 when not present) :

```
Date,x,y,z
1,2,0,0
2,3,5,0
3,0,8,9
```

I do not know beforehand the names of the metrics. At the moment I'm loading the results in python and reshaping using pandas but surely there is a PostgreSQL way to do it.

How to achieve the above in PostgreSQL ?

Comment: Do you really need them as explicit columns? I tend more and more to return dynamic results like that as a JSON value with key/value pairs - especially if the number of "columns" is not known in advance nor is it constant. What if the query returned something like `1, '{"x": 2, "y": 0, "z": 0}'` instead?

Comment: yes i ended up doing that and leaving the reshaping itself to my nodejs server.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `conditional aggregation` with `case when expression`

```
select date, 
       max(case when metric='x' then value end) as x,
       max(case when metric='y' then value end) as y,
       max(case when metric='z' then value end) as z
from tablename
group by date
```

Comment: i do not know the names of the metrics beforehand as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Chapo, than you need dynamic pivot

Comment: Great to know a solution exists ! Could you please show me how that would work in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [crosstab](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/tablefunc.html)

```
 select * from crosstab('select date, metric ,value from metric_table order by date, metric ,value '
                       ,'select  metric from metric_table group by metric  order by metric') 
                  as ct( date integer ,y integer,x integer, z integer);
```

But beware, `"as ct( date integer ,y integer,x integer, z integer)"` part must be dynamically created before calling query, based on `"select  metric from metric_table group by metric order by metric"` result set